# Wordpress custom post type, with two image galleries

Tags: wordpress, media, custom-post-type

i need to create a custom post type in wordpress with the following requirements:

- Title
- Subtitle
- Brief description
- Long description
- Outer Image gallery
- Inner Image gallery

Im having trouble creating two separate image galleries for this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

https://gist.github.com/897503
Give it a try.. :D

Comment: That's quite awesome!  Any hints on how will the information will be saved - and how do i read it in my template?

Comment: <?php  

    query_posts("post_type=my&showposts=-1");  

    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            
 if ( $attachments = get_children(array(
  'post_type' => 'attachment',
  'post_mime_type'=>'image',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_parent' => $post->ID
 )));
  
 foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
  
  echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'full' , true, false, '');

 } 
 
 endwhile; 
 
endif; 

?>